Sorting JSON object and filtering
This is my code for combining and grouping data from 2 CSV file.
const csv = require('csv-parser')
const fs = require('fs')

var matchesData = {}
var innData = []
var convertedObject = {}

function convertIntoObject(){
  for (let i = 0; i < innData.length; i++) {

    if(!convertedObject[innData[i].SEASON]){
            convertedObject[innData[i].SEASON] = {}
        }
    if(!convertedObject[innData[i].SEASON][innData[i].BOWLER]){
      convertedObject[innData[i].SEASON][innData[i].BOWLER] = {}
    }

    if(!convertedObject[innData[i].SEASON][innData[i].BOWLER].totalRuns && 
      !convertedObject[innData[i].SEASON][innData[i].BOWLER].balls &&
      !convertedObject[innData[i].SEASON][innData[i].BOWLER].economy
     )
    convertedObject[innData[i].SEASON][innData[i].BOWLER] = 
   {    "totalRuns": 0,
        "balls": 0, 
        "economy": 0
    }


    convertedObject[innData[i].SEASON][innData[i].BOWLER] = 
   {    "totalRuns": Number(convertedObject[innData[i].SEASON][innData[i].BOWLER].totalRuns) + (innData[i].TOTAL_RUNS - innData[i].BYE_RUNS - innData[i].LEGBYE_RUNS),
        "balls": Number(convertedObject[innData[i].SEASON][innData[i].BOWLER].balls) + 1, 
        "economy": (Number(convertedObject[innData[i].SEASON][innData[i].BOWLER].totalRuns) / (convertedObject[innData[i].SEASON][innData[i].BOWLER].balls / 6)).toFixed(2)
    }
}
}

fs.createReadStream('matches.csv')
  .pipe(csv())
  .on('data', (data) => {
  matchesData[data.MATCH_ID] = data.SEASON
  })
  .on('end', () => {
    //console.log(matchesData)
  });
  

  fs.createReadStream('deliveries.csv')
  .pipe(csv())
  .on('data', (data) => {
    innData.push({...data, "SEASON": matchesData[data.MATCH_ID]})
  })
   .on('end', () => {
    convertIntoObject()
    fs.writeFileSync("output.txt", JSON.stringify(convertedObject))
  });


Output that's generated is
{
    "2008": {
        "P Kumar": {
            "totalRuns": 366,
            "balls": 275,
            "economy": "8.01"
        },
        "Z Khan": {
            "totalRuns": 357,
            "balls": 258,
            "economy": "8.31"
        },
    },
    "2009": {
        "AA Noffke": {
            "totalRuns": 366,
            "balls": 275,
            "economy": "8.01"
        },
        "JH Kallis": {
            "totalRuns": 357,
            "balls": 258,
            "economy": "8.31"
        },
    }
}


Now I want to get top 10 teams for each year with best economy. I am not able to find a solution as to how to sort this data based on economy key and then filter top 10 teams.
I want this output also be updated in the following format:
    "2008": [
        ["P Kumar": {
            "totalRuns": 366,
            "balls": 275,
            "economy": "8.01"
        }],
        ["Z Khan": {
            "totalRuns": 357,
            "balls": 258,
            "economy": "8.31"
        }],
    ],
    "2009": [
        ["AA Noffke": {
            "totalRuns": 366,
            "balls": 275,
            "economy": "8.01"
        }],
        ["JH Kallis": {
            "totalRuns": 357,
            "balls": 258,
            "economy": "8.31"
        }],
    ]
}   
    ```



Your required output is not valid syntax. Maybe you want [{name, totalRuns, balls, economy}, {name, totalRuns, balls, econmy}] ?

Let's start we'll figure out the valid syntax output later.
My play is to get keys of arrays, aggregate items, sort, slice etc let's try


var topK = 10
var objInput = {
  "2008": {
    "P Kumar": {
      "totalRuns": 366,
      "balls": 275,
      "economy": "8.01"
    },
    "Z Khan": {
      "totalRuns": 357,
      "balls": 258,
      "economy": "8.31"
    },
  },
  "2009": {

    "JH Kallis": {
      "totalRuns": 357,
      "balls": 258,
      "economy": "8.31"
    },
    "AA Noffke": {
      "totalRuns": 366,
      "balls": 275,
      "economy": "8.01"
    },
  }
}

function process(objInput) {
  var result = {}
  var result2 = {}

  Object.entries(objInput).forEach(function([year, value]) {
    var arr = []
    var obj = {}
    Object.entries(value).forEach(function([name, data]) {
      arr.push({
        name,
        ...data
      })
    })
    arr.sort(function(a, b) {
      return b.economy - a.economy
    })
    result[year] = arr.slice(0, topK)

    var obj = {}
    result[year].forEach(function(item) {
      var name = item.name
      delete item.name
      obj[name] = item
    })
    result2[year] = obj;


  })

  // suggested output
  // return result;

  // similar to required output
  return result2;

}

console.log(process(objInput))
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
}




Thank you. This code seems working to generate the output in the object format. Now I need to convert it to array format. But let me try first at my end.

ok, but here's a spoiler:  the answer is already within the answer

Second answer in result object does not have player name. Let me try from my end.
